# How to ensure uniqueness in manytomany fields in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

So say you have models like following:

```
class User(models.Model):

class Tag(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(unique=True)

class Subscription(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("owner", "tags"),)

class Post(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
```

From the above, you can see that users can have subscriptions based on the tags. Ideally you want to ensure that each set of subscriptions for a user is unique? that's why i added unique_together to the meta class. But i'm getting this error:

```
Subscription: (models.E013) 'unique_together' refers to a ManyToManyField 'tags', but ManyToManyFields are not permitted in 'unique_together'.
```

Any ideas? Thx.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>You don't need to specify unique_together. The ManyToManyField in Django is unique by default. Try adding the same relationship twice and you will see you have only one record.</strike>

There is a useful [Django Snippet](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2552/) for this which I've modified for your example:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import m2m_changed
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.utils import IntegrityError

class User(models.Model):
    pass

class Tag(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(unique=True)

class Subscription(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("owner", "tags"),)

class Post(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Subscription.tags.through)
def verify_uniqueness(sender, **kwargs):
    subscription = kwargs.get('instance', None)
    action = kwargs.get('action', None)
    tags = kwargs.get('pk_set', None)

    if action == 'pre_add':
        for tag in tags:
            if Subscription.objects.filter(owner=subscription.owner).filter(tag=tag):
                raise IntegrityError('Subscription with owner %s already exists for tag %s' % (subscription.owner, tag))
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question as the OP needs uniqueness of the `User` and set of `tags` through the `Subscription` model

Comment: Ah, I misread the question. Thanks for pointing that out. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the replies! i think this is in the right direction of what I want. :)
there's a nuance here tho. it's not the duplicated tag i care about. i want to ensure the set is unique. So when i want to insert a new set of tags in subscription, it would be nice to figure out if the new set is unique, and only insert the new set if that's the case.

Comment: For anyone trying to use this, I don't think this is thread safe. As an example, if you have multiple "gunicorn" processes you can't be sure that this solution works for two concurrent requests. If that is not the case for you then its a good solution. Otherwise I suggest using `through` in ManyToManyField and in the middle table handle uniqueness using `unique_together`